# Need help with MySQL Query using not like

Tags: mysql

My table is having entries in following way.

```
ID | Value
----------
1  | Apple
2  | Apple
2  | Grape
```

Here I want to extract all the ID's which should not have Apple

Now if we use not like 'Apple' in the query, then we will get ID 2 as Grape is there.

So I would like to know is there any way to extract ID's which should not have Apple.

I can't use subquery kind of thing.
And main thing is in our application, we are using this query as generic one, means it should support for all filters (Like, Not Like). So here i can't use subquery.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Giving a field that is not unique the name 'ID' is bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

You can do with sub query

```
select id from table 
where id not in (
                 select id from table  
                 where value ='Apple'
                )
```

Answer (score 1):

may be:

```
select * from dataTable where value not like 'Apple' and id not in(select id from datatable where value like 'Apple')
```

but wondering duplicate id for different values...

Comment: You do not need to add `value not like 'Apple'` in your outer query

Comment: @Shakti, this is true, but it will probably speed things up - allows query planner to do execution that will prune some of the records earlier without a need to use more expensive (even if it is not correlated subquery) NOT IN

Comment: @Unreason: Adding more condition which is not needed at all. Speed things up?

Comment: @Shakti Singh: Yes. Try it. Reasoning goes like this: assume comparison `not like 'Apple'` is n times faster compared to `NOT IN (SELECT ...)` (which it is, one is comparison of varchar field and constant and the other needs to walk a temporary built table or do an index_subquery, compare plans). So, this additional and unnecessary condition has a chance to discard the records early without using the more expensive one. Still, to justify it you need to have a certain percentage of such 'early apple' cases, so it does depend on the stats (therefore I said it will probably speed things up).

Answer (score 1):

...and, one more query -

```
SELECT id FROM fruits 
  GROUP BY id 
  HAVING COUNT(IF(value = 'Apple', 1, NULL)) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

What the others say, but with the DISTINCT keyword, viz:

```
select distinct id from table 
where id not in (
                 select id from table  
                 where value ='Apple'
                )
```

Comment: It is not clear that this is a good path. Need for DISTINCT depends on the future use of data. Yes, to get a proper set (no repeating elements) you do need it. However, DISTINCT is expensive and should not be automatically thrown in (normally you would avoid it by proper design; in this case repeating id's suggest bad design and possible need for DISTINCT, still it should be thought through)

Answer (score 0):

For completeness here's EXIST version

```
SELECT id 
FROM table t
WHERE NOT EXIST (
                 SELECT 1 
                 FROM table t2 
                 WHERE value ='Apple' AND
                       t1.id = t2.id
                )
```

(normally these correlated subqueries perform worse then uncorrelated counterpart, but YMMV depending on data patterns, also indexes might make orders of magnitude difference, even on small sets)

**EDIT:**

You can also check this [article](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/) to see the similarities and differences between the three approaches and some reasoning (though conclusion does not necessarily apply in your case - you have a single table, but it shows how to analyze; especially interesting would be to compare plan and performance of Devart's solution).